# UDP Sockets aren't receiving all the packets

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, udp

At the moment I'm working on a project where I have to build an RTP client and server with the .NET via C#. The current question concern the the client side.

I created a UDP Socket like the following for listening to the server :

```
Socket RTPSocket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

I also created an array of bytes to store received bytes :

```
byte[] RTPBuffer = new byte[1500];
```

The size is at 1500 because after packet analysis with wireshark i saw that the max packet size sent by VLC was 1428. After that i created a thread for the listening process, this thread contains the following instructions :

```
 while(!Disposing)
 {
     RTPSocket.Receive(RTPBuffer);

     OnRTPDataReceived(RTPBuffer);
 }
```

The OnRTPDataReceived instruction raise an event wich is handled by the following method :

```
    public void RTPPacketReceived(object sender, byte[] packet)
    {
        PacketQueue.Enqueue(packet);
    }
```

Finally the bytes array contained in the PacketQueue Queue are processed by another thread but this is off topic.

The problem is that my socket is sometimes receiving one packet out of two and sometines one out of three and some other times every packets. In fact it's random.

I looked to this kind of problem in different forums but I didn't find any solutions to resolve my problem.

I also tried to set a better priority to the listening thread and a lower one to the others, didn't worked. Last thing I tried was reduce the number of instruction after receiving data to see if the process duration was the cause of the packet loss but this too didn't worked.

Thanks in advance for your time !

Comment: Do you have any documentation? Read it first and **NEVER DO THAT :** _"The size is at 1500 because after packet analysis with wireshark i saw that the max packet size sent by VLC was 1428"_

Comment: UDP is not a guaranteed delivery system, packets are expected to be lost. If you need guaranteed delivery, you need to use tcp

Comment: You need to set up a protocol that will ensure 1. completeness, 2. order. UDP packets are not guaranteed to come in order or at all. Most implementations I know use a package-no to ensure order. If packages are missing, a retransmit can be requested or some other measures be taken (for example drop the whole frame when streaming video).

Comment: And to add to the accurate information above, you aren't even guaranteed any given UDP datagram will be delivered no more than once. You can get duplicated datagrams as well. Bottom line: your question makes no sense, because there's nothing in your post that suggests anything out of the ordinary. Did you take any time to study the UDP protocol before trying to write code that uses it? Do you have a valid question to ask?

Comment: " i saw that the max packet size sent by VLC was 1428" - I *guess* VLC is doing this to avoid packet fragmentation (which happens at 1500 if I remember correctly). But generally a packet can be much larger. (~65k I believe - would have to look that up to say for sure). Fragmentation is done on IP layer, so you won't "see" it. But if only one of the fragments is lost, the whole IP frame is dropped. So limiting the packet size below the frag threshold will just ensure a 1:1 relation of UDP and IP packets.

Comment: Max size for packet over UDP is 65535, however VLC never send me packet with size over 1428. Thing i forget to say, I'm working in local, my server and client are on the same computer. Packet can be lost even in local ?

Comment: I know that the UDP does not guarantee the delivery of the packets and the receiving order but the TCP protocol will increase the latency (because of the check it made for the order and the delivery) which is not acceptable for live video surveillance. Moreover the delivery order isn't a problem, I can check the order later in my program with RTP sequence number parameter.

Comment: Many security recommendations have network devices configured to drop packet fragments, as fragmented packets can be used in DOS attacks.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_fragmentation_attack  And yes, UDP can be dropped on purely local-to-local transmissions if the sender(s) are creating packets faster then the reader(s) can read them - a lot of UDP-handling code will drop the packet if it runs into a full buffer of any kind, anywhere.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I finally found the problem, it was in an other thread.